# QNX Momentics: GoogleMock - Return has value, in function returning void error

Tags: c++, c++11, googletest, googlemock, qnx

I need to write mock methods for a class, provided to us by a third party supplier. The class, that I need to mock has virtual methods and I am mocking them in my mock class.

This is the original class:

```
    class Derived : public Base
{

public:
    virtual void addResource(const Resource& resource, std::string resourceURL);
    virtual void removeResource(const Resource& resource);
...
};
```

Just to let you know, these two methods are virtual in the Base class, too.

This is the Mock class:

```
class MockDerived : public Derived {
 public:
     MockDerived (std::string name);

  MOCK_METHOD2(addResource,
      void(const Resource& resource, std::string resourceURL));

  MOCK_METHOD1(removeResource,
      void(const Resource& resource));
};
```

All this works fine. I am executing tests without a problem. However, in QNX Momentics (The QNX version is 7.0), which is really just Eclipse, it gives me the following error:

```
Return has value, in function returning void
```

Anybody has an idea what I need to do in order to remove the errors. It still works, but it is annoying to have this error and who knows what can go wrong in the future.

Comment: Is this the issue reported by your IDE (Eclipse) - not by compiler? Just ignore.

Comment: Yes, it is reported by the IDE. Currently I am ignoring it, but it looks bad in the project explorer, showing some errors. So I was wondering if the IDE can ignore it as well

Comment: report this as a problem in IDE (QNX , Eclippse bugzilla - I do not know where it can go). I am afraid you cannot do more - but maybe there is some filtering in your IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appeared to be an issue with the IDE. When building the project using Command Line it all works fine and no error is printed. I will probably follow up this with QNX.